# Wavefunction operators and the observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, observables, eigenvalue

So I got this from the exam I had yesterday. I couldn't really answer it other and it played on my mind through the night

Show that if a wave function $\psi$ , is an eigenfunction of an operator [Q], then the observable Q is sharp for that wave function.

I said that if  it is an eigenfunction then performing the operator must be a whole multiple of the wavefunction and then tried to bull my way through it. What would you guys have accepted as an answer.

I mean I know that 
$\Delta Q=\sqrt{\overline{Q^2}- \overline{Q}^2}$

But how do I translate my knowledge across to give an answer that if the observable is sharp this reduces to 0?

Comment: Did you mean $\Delta{Q} =\sqrt{\langle Q^2\rangle-\langle Q\rangle^2}$ ?

Comment: I know it has a bar right across the first one and a bar over just the Q for the second then squared thats what it has in the textbook. I just used the form that u gave when I needed it yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the system is in an eigenstate of $Q$, then a measurement of $Q$ will yield the corresponding eigenvalue with probability one.  An implication of this is that $Q$ has vanishing uncertainty in the state $\psi$ as you note.  Here's how to show that mathematically:

If $\psi$ is a normalized eigenfunction of $Q$, then there exists some real number $q$, it's eigenvalue, for which
$$
  Q\psi = q \psi
$$
and therefore
$$
  Q^2\psi = q^2\psi.
$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
  \langle Q\rangle^2 &= \langle\psi,Q\psi\rangle^2= q^2\langle\psi,\psi\rangle^2 =q^2\\
  \langle Q^2\rangle &= \langle\psi,Q^2\psi\rangle = q^2\langle\psi,\psi\rangle=q^2
\end{align}
so the uncertainty in measuring $Q$ for the state $\psi$ is
\begin{align}
  \Delta Q = \sqrt{\langle Q^2\rangle - \langle Q\rangle^2} = \sqrt{q^2-q^2} = 0
\end{align}

Comment: @JesseRoss Sure thing.